# Complement of closed dense set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $C$ be its closed and dense subset.
Then is it possible for $X-C$ to be dense in X?

I think $C$ doesn't have to be closed, and in that case $X-C$ can be also dense.
But how about $C$ being closed?

Comment: If $C$ is closed and dense in $X$, then $C=X$.

Answer (score 4):

If $C$ is closed then its closure $\bar{C} =C$ itself. But because $C$ is dense, we know that $\bar{C}=X$. So $X\setminus C=X\setminus \bar{C} =X\setminus X=\emptyset$

Comment: Oh, I have been foolish...thank you all :)