# Is $L^1(X) \cap L^2(X)$ a closed subspace of $L^2(X)$ and $L^1(X)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Suppose that $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. Could we say that $L^1(X)\cap L^2(X)$ is closed subspace of $L^1(X)$ and $L^2(X)$?

Comment: If $X=\Bbb R$, then the space of smooth compactly supported functions (or simple functions) $C\subset L^1\cap L^2 $ is dense in either $L^1$ or $L^2$. In particular $L^1\cap L^2$ is dense in either $L^1$ or $L^2$.

Comment: Someone needs to point out that the question really makes no sense! If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space there's no such thing as $L^p(X)$. People talk about $L^p(\mathbb R)$; that makes sense only because it refers to the _default_ measure on $\mathbb R$, namely Lebesgue measure. There is no default measure on a locally compact Hausdorff space. (yes, we all knew all this. Except possibly the OP didn't...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, for any locally compact Hausdorff $X$, and Radon measure $\mu$ on $X$,  the set of  all continuous compactly supported function $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^p(X)$ for all $1\leq p<\infty$ (theorem 3.14 of "Real and complex analysis" by Walter Rudin). Hence $C_c(X)\subset L^1(X) \cap L^p(X)$, and so $L^1(X) \cap L^p(X)$ is dense in $L^p(X)$, for all $1\leq p<\infty$.( when $X=N$ , $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in N}\not\in\ell^1(N)$ but $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in N}\in\ell^2(N)$. Hence $\ell^1(N)\cap\ell^2(N)\neq \ell^2(N)$, consequently $\ell^1(X)\cap\ell^2(X)$ is not closed in $\ell^2(X)$, becuase $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in N}\in\overline{\ell^1(X)\cap\ell^2(X)}^{\|.\|_2}$ and $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in N}\not\in\ell^1(X)\cap\ell^2(X)$. Similarly $\overline{\ell^1(X)\cap\ell^2(X)}^{\|.\|_1}=\ell^1(X)\neq \ell^1(X)\cap\ell^2(X)$)

Comment: Why density implies closure? In infinite dimensional spaces, there are many subspaces that are dense but not closed.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It doesn't imply closure, density implies the opposite of closure.

Comment: @avid19: so $L^2$, that is trivially dense in $L^2$, is not closed in $L^2$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That is correct. However if a subspace is dense in a larger space, it is not closed.

Comment: That looks false, too. The Schwarz space is dense in $L^2$ and the Schwarz space is closed.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio but with different topologies! The limit of any Cauchy sequence in $S$ is also in $S$ with respect to the seminorm topology. It's dense in $L^2$ with respect to the $L^2$ topology.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio See this. The only closed, dense subset of a TVS is the space itself. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/980311/complement-of-closed-dense-set

Comment: All right, got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's not. Consider $f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{x^{1+1/n}}\in L^1([1,\infty))\cap L^2([1,\infty))\subset L^2([1,\infty))$. Then:

$$\|f_n(x)-\frac1x\|_2=\int_1^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x^{1+1/n}}-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2dx=\frac{1}{2/n+1}-\frac{2}{1/n+1}+1\to 0$$ as $n\to\infty$. However $\frac1x\not\in L^1([1,\infty))$.

Comment: However, $\left\{\frac{1}{x^{1+1/n}}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ is not a Cauchy sequence in $L^1(1,+\infty)$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It's not. I'm just saying that $L^1\cap L^2$ is not a closed subspace of $L^2$.

Comment: So we must find a Cauchy sequence in $L^1\cap L^2$ that does not converge in $L^1\cap L^2$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Which I did. This is a Cauchy sequence in $L^2 \cap L^1\subset L^2$

Comment: It is not a Cauchy sequence in $L^1$, hence it cannot be a Cauchy sequence in $L^1\cap L^2$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You're misinterpreting the problem. He is treating $L^2 \cap L^2$ as a set, which can be though of as a subspace of either $L^1$ or $L^2$. Is this a closed subspace of either $L^2$ or $L^2$?

Comment: what is your definition of a Cauchy sequence in $L^1\cap L^2$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It depends on whether we consider $L^1 \cap L^2 \subset L^1 $ or $L^1 \cap L^2 \subset L^2 $

Comment: I'd rather say that a Cauchy sequence in $L^1\cap L^2$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^1$ *and* in $L^2$, the set and the norm mustn't change depending on how we "see" them.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio What topology are you using on $L^1 \cap L^2$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Why should it require two different topologies to be Cauchy? That doesn't make sense. The topology should come from the superspace you are considering -- namely, $L_1$ or $L_2$.

Comment: @PhilipHoskins: but I'd also say that the most natural way to equip $A=L^1\cap L^2$ with a norm is to define: $$\|f\|_A = \|f\|_1+\|f\|_2,$$ why should we give to $L^1$ or $L^2$ an asymmetric privilege?

Comment: For instance, when defining Sobolev spaces we do not require that some derivative belongs to $L^p$, but that *every* derivative up to a certain order belongs to $L^p$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The problem explicitly says "as a subspace of $L^1$ and $L^2$". Meaning we use the $L^1$ or $L^2$ topologies.

Comment: There are more information about the norm that @Jack D'Aurizio  mentioned in this paper:
"Closed Ideals in the Group Algebra $L^1 (G)\cap L^2 (G)$" by C. Robert Warner

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio What norm is most natural has nothing to do with the question! In the asker's question, we are viewing $L_1 \cap L_2$ as a *subspace*. Once you've picked a superspace, then it only makes sense to call $L_1 \cap L_2$ a *subspace* if you give it the *subspace topology*.

Comment: This answer does not show $L^1 \cap L^2$ is not closed in $L^1$. I think this is probably part of the question and explains the comments made by @JackD'Aurizio.

Comment: @PVAL I think you misunderstand the question. This answers shows that the conclusion to the question is generally *no.* The point is that $(L_1 \cap L_2, \Vert \cdot \Vert_1)$ and $(L_1 \cap L_2, \Vert \cdot \Vert_2)$ are subspaces of *different vector spaces*. One of which may fail to be closed in the topology of that vector space, as demonstrated in this answer. Answering the question does not require one to give an example where closure fails in both topologies.